# MVC Blank JsonResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I'm returning a JsonResult as part of an Orchard CMS Site (MVC 4) and it suddenly stopped working (specifics below).

Here is an example from my controller:

```
public JsonResult GetStartDate()
{
    //a previous version of this question was different here
    var startDate = _Settings.DateOpen.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MaxValue);
    if (startDate < DateTime.Now)
        startDate = DateTime.Now;


    var start = new
    {
        year = startDate.Time.Year,
        month = (startDate.Time.Month - 1)
    };

    return Json(start, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It should be returning actual data. I have verified that the action is being hit and that "start" contains the correct data before being passed into the Json method.

If I navigate directly to the URL, I get a blank white screen.

Inspecting the result of an AJAX request shows that the call fails, the response body is an empty string , the status is "parsererror" and the actual error throws is "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input."

POST requests work for some reason, this issue only applies to GETs.

This problem is with *all* JSON GETs, not just any specific method.

What could be affecting the data between the Json method and the client receiving the response?

Comment: Is there any change if you change the result type from JsonResult tom ActionResult?

Comment: Nope. But I did have a change a bit ago. Current Chrome suddenly started receiving the results. All I did was start the site again to show someone that it wasn't working. IE, Firefox, and Chrome Canary are still not showing. I've disabled the cache on both versions of chrome but no change. Madness!

Comment: Is your method being cached add this decorator to see if it makes any difference [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]

Comment: That seems to have worked! Thanks a lot. If you'd like to edit your previous answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all MVC methods are cached. This can lead to issues during the change/debug cycle. For starters you can turn off caching during development using the decorator below.

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)] 
public ActionResult MyMethod()
```

You may want to wrap all methods with a caching scheme that is defined in the web.config. This allows caching to be controlled via one configuration change which comes in handy during development.

```
 <system.web>
    <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <clear />
          <add varyByParam="*" duration="0" name="MyCachePlan" />          
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
 </system.web>
```

And use the following decorator:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "MyCachePlan")]
public ActionResult MyMethod()
```

Comment: Oops! Thanks for catching that. Unfortunately, that was unrelated though. I edited the question with a (slightly) different method that has the same problem.